# How to back trace a function call?

Tags: c#

I would like to trace the flow of function calls from one specific functions start and until its end.

I know that it is possible to get the stack trace at any place in the code, 
however I do not know which path the function will take. I am trying to fix a bug and I do not know where the point of interest is exactly. Thats why I want to see the flow of function calls (without using the debugger which is time consuming), so that I can narrow down the possibilities.

Is it possible to back trace the starting function call?

Comment: (1) Set breakpoint at point of interest, (2) debug program and wait for it to stop at the breakpoint, (3) open the Stack Trace windows, (4) Profit.

Comment: I am trying to fix a bug and I do not know where the point of interest is exactly. Thats why I want to see the flow of function calls (without using the debugger which is time consuming), so that I can narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: If you have Visual Studio Enterprise, you might be able to get some help from using [IntelliTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd572114.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

this is called call trace and you can see this in visual studio and using third party tools as well,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439516(v=vs.85).aspx

You can use jetbrains tools as third party:

https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/help/Call_Stack.html

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Navigation/stackTraceExplorer.html

Hope these will help :)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this would require that you already know where you want to look. My question may not have been clear enough, so I updated it. I want to know a functions subsequent calls, after that function has ended, without having to debug my way through the whole thing. Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, using [Trace Points](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/232dxah7(v=vs.100).aspx)-

1. Trace one function at a time;
2. Trace all functions.

---

**Trace one function**

Put the trace point in your function of interest. Whenever the trace point is hit, make it print the calling function. This I think can be done by printing the property - `$FUNCTION`.

This way you will know the caller of your current function, when you run the code, in the *Output* Window of Visual Studio. Perform the same activity in the caller function now and keep bubbling up the functions as far as you want.

---

**Trace all functions**

If all your functions are in one class or local enough for you, simply put the same trace point in all of them. Let your code run and you will be able to see the call trace in the *Output* Window of Visual Studio.

---

**Steps to add a trace point**

1. Right click on the line you want to add tracepoint on;
2. In the drop-down menu > Breakpoint > Insert Tracepoint;
3. The window that open will explain how to print the calling function at that tracepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` class for this.
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 var stackObject = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true);
 string stackTrace = stackObject.ToString();
```

A good example is provided [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223611/How-to-log-the-current-call-stack-in-NET).